# The tabbar does not fit all devices

Tags: ios, swiftui

The tabbar does not fit all devices. I think I should use a GHeometryReader, but I've tried and failed.

I managed to get it to work by changing the offset(x: x) of all the icons, but it's not the right solution because there are lots of different screen sizes.

How can I make the tabbar fit all screen sizes ?

[image]

This is how it works with the following code :

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    
    //Custom type
    
    //Environnements
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    //State or Binding String
    @State private var icons: [String] = ["house.fill", "creditcard.fill", "plus", "dollarsign.circle.fill", "rectangle.stack.fill"]
    
    //State or Binding Int, Float and Double
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    @State private var offsetSelectedTab: CGFloat = 0
    var tabBarWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20
    
    //State or Binding Bool
    
    //Enum
    
    //Computed var
    var tabItemWidth: CGFloat { return tabBarWidth / 5 }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var indicator: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(radius: 4, x: 0, y: 4)
            .offset(x: CGFloat(selectedTab) * (tabBarWidth / 5) + 12, y: 0)
            .animation(.spring(), value: selectedTab)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            indicator
            
            HStack {
                IconTabBar(icon: "house.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 0 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "creditcard.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 1 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "plus", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 2 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "dollarsign.circle.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 3 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "rectangle.stack.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 4 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
            }
            .frame(width: tabBarWidth)
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 6)
        .frame(width: tabBarWidth)
        .background(Color.colorPastelBlue)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .padding()
    }//END body
    
    //MARK: Fonctions
    
}//END struct

//MARK: - Preview
struct TabBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @State static var selectedTabPreview: Int = 0
    
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBarView(selectedTab: $selectedTabPreview)
    }
}

//MARK: ICON IN TABBAR

struct IconTabBar: View {
    
    var icon: String
    @Binding var selectedTabIndex: Int
    var onPressTabBarItem: () -> Void
    let tabItemWidth: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            onPressTabBarItem()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .foregroundColor(.colorLabel)
                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
        }
        .frame(width: tabItemWidth, height: 35)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share an image of how the tab bar is not fitting with the device, so at least we can understand the difference.

Comment: @SamirBagaria Sorry, I thought I'd added it. I've just edited the post with the video of what I currently have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
@ViewBuilder
var indicator: some View {
    HStack{
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(radius: 4, x: 0, y: 4)
            .animation(.spring(), value: selectedTab)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: tabItemWidth)
    .offset(x: CGFloat(selectedTab) * tabItemWidth, y: 0)
}
```

In this I have done changes in offset.

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    
    //Custom type
    
    //Environnements
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    //State or Binding String
    @State private var icons: [String] = ["house.fill", "creditcard.fill", "plus", "dollarsign.circle.fill", "rectangle.stack.fill"]
    
    //State or Binding Int, Float and Double
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    @State private var offsetSelectedTab: CGFloat = 0
    var tabBarWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20
    
    //State or Binding Bool
    
    //Enum
    
    //Computed var
    var tabItemWidth: CGFloat { return tabBarWidth / 5 }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var indicator: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(radius: 4, x: 0, y: 4)
            .offset(x: CGFloat(selectedTab) * tabItemWidth + (5 * UIScreen.main.scale), y: 0)
            .animation(.spring(), value: selectedTab)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 35)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            indicator
            
            HStack {
                IconTabBar(icon: "house.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 0 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "creditcard.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 1 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "plus", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 2 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "dollarsign.circle.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 3 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
                
                IconTabBar(icon: "rectangle.stack.fill", selectedTabIndex: $selectedTab, onPressTabBarItem: {
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 170, damping: 30)) { selectedTab = 4 }
                }, tabItemWidth: tabItemWidth)
            }
            .frame(width: tabBarWidth)
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 6)
        .frame(width: tabBarWidth)
        .background(Color.green)
        .cornerRadius(12)
    }//END body
    
    //MARK: Fonctions
    
}


struct IconTabBar: View {
    
    var icon: String
    @Binding var selectedTabIndex: Int
    var onPressTabBarItem: () -> Void
    let tabItemWidth: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button {
                onPressTabBarItem()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: icon)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
            }
            .frame(height: 35,alignment: .center)
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Also added Spacer in IconTabBar.

Comment: I've just tried it, the code works fine on an iPhone 14 Pro Max but on an iPhone 14 it's no good. The icons are not aligned with the indicator

Comment: @KaayZenn please check the indicator view, I have edited the answer.